# Vue method to list each object in an array of objects leads to errors

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, laravel, vue.js

This is the dropdown component used to give a list of all grids in all pages. There are multiple pages and grids within those pages.

```
    <v-dropdown
        :items="pageGrids"
        :item-text="gridNamesAndPages"
        return-object
    />
```

gridNamesAndPages is under methods:

```
    gridNamesAndPages: item => item.name + ' • (Page: ' + item.page_name.name + ')',
```

This is the method used to assign the empty array summaryGrids to all grids for this project:

```
    getAllPageGrids() {
        apiClientGet(
            routes["pages.getAllPageGrids"],
            null,
            response => {
                this.pageGrids.push(response.data);
            }
        );
    },
```

The function in the controller:

```
    public function getAllPageGrids()
    {
        return Auth::user()->client->grids()->get();
    }
```

SummaryGrids are in this format. There could be multiple grids so whilst this only shows 3 there could be 100:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "AS",
            "grid_cols": [
                {
                    "id": 16,
                    "grid_id": 3,
                    "order": 1,
                    "header": "Col 1",
                }
            ],
            "page_name": {
                "name": "Page 1"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "SF",
            "grid_cols": [
                {
                    "id": 21,
                    "grid_id": 4,
                    "header": "Name",
                },
                {
                    "id": 22,
                    "grid_id": 4,
                    "header": "Reference",
                }
            ],
            "page_name": {
                "name": "Page 1"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "WE",
            "grid_cols": [
                {
                    "id": 24,
                    "grid_id": 5,
                    "header": "Name",
                }
            ],
            "page_name": {
                "name": "Page 2"
            }
        }
    ]
```

However I continue to get this error:

[image]
[image]

I can't see anything wrong with the way the code is structured. Would anyone know if I've actually written it incorrectly?

(On request I've also included the custom v-dropdown component)

```
<template>
    <v-select
        :class="`text-field-${color || 'white'}`"
        outlined dense
        v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs"
    >
        <slot>
            <!--  -->
        </slot>
    </v-select>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: {
        color: {
            type: String|null,
            default: null
        }
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I'd recommend tagging this as `vue` in some way, use the version that is specific to yours

Comment: what is this v-dropdown component? can you share it's code / docs?

Comment: It's a custom component based on v-select, I've added the code at the bottom

Comment: `gridNamesAndPages` is expecting a single argument (`item`) being passed in, but you're not doing so in your template.

Comment: That makes sense, though since :items expects an array of multiple objects, then doesn't :item-text expect to handle each object (item) in that array and not just one?